# improve perfomance of a REST Service

Tags: c#, performance, rest

I have method which calls a stored procedure 300 times in a for loop and each time the stored procedure returns me 1200 records. How can i improve this ? I cannot eliminate the 300 calls but is there any otherways i can try out. I am using REST service impletemented through ASP.NET and using IBATIS for database connectivity

Comment: You should optimize your sp, post the code of your sp on codereview.

Comment: its joining three tables and returns the records

Comment: 300 calls to an sp is a bad implementation, try to improve this.

Comment: rest is not responsible of poor performance. how can you have good perf with 300 calls ?

Comment: Yes I want to know different ways i can improve the performance

Comment: It is unlikely that you'll be able to improve performance in any meaningful way until you're no longer making 300 database calls.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot eliminate the 300 calls

**Eliminate the 300 calls.**

Even if all you can do is to just add another stored procedure which calls the original stored procedure 300 times, aggregating the results, you should see a massive performance gain.

Even better if you can write a new stored procedure that replicates the original functionality but is structured more appropriately for your specific use case, and call that, once, instead.

Making 300 round trips between your code and your database quite simply is going to take time, *even where the code and the database are on the same system*.

Once this bit of horrible is resolved, there will be other things you can look to optimise, if required.

Comment: the problem is DBA are not letting to increase the sql CPU utilization time. earliyer the sp was written to return 360,000 records with all the possible indexes in place. it took 6 sends to execute. they dont want to lock the tables for that much of time..that is why had to call it in a loop

Comment: Do you care about locks for your purposes? `select col from mytable with (nolock)`

Comment: You could also consider implementing a caching layer, if that fits with your scenario.

Comment: And it's somewhat perverse for your DBA to force that requirement, yet allow you to call the stored procedure 300 times.

Comment: nolock cannot be used as then the non comitted data would be return by the SP isnt it ? that is another concern DBA raised

Comment: they are ok to call the sp 300 times with 1200 records but they dont want the tables to be locked for 6 seconds

Comment: That (nolock -> return uncommitted data) is correct. If that's not okay in your scenario, don't do it.

Comment: earliyer the response time of the REST call was 40 seconds, in that the SP was returning 360,000 which takes 6 secnds the sp to execute. Then after the refactor calling the sp 300 times with 1200 records each time now the response time is 1 min and 9 seconds

Comment: I remain convinced that the only reasonable way to proceed is to start by reducing the number of database round trips. The specifics of how you do this are not really answerable with the information given here, and possibly not at all without being in your environment. You really need to work with your DBA to refactor the whole interaction to find some kind of compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Measure.

Measure the amount of time spent inside the server-side code. Measure the amount of that time that is spent in the stored procedure. Measure the amount of time spent at the client part. Do some math, and you have a rough estimate for network time and other overheads.

Returning 1200 records, I would *expect* network bandwidth to be one of the main issues; you could perhaps investigate whether a different serialization engine (with the same output type) might help, or perhaps whether adding compression (gzip / deflate) support would be beneficial (meaning: reduced bandwidth being more important than the increased CPU required).

Latency might be important if you are calling the REST service 300 times; maybe you can parallelize slightly, or make fewer big calls rather than lots of small calls.

You could batch the SQL code, so you only make a few trips to the DB (calling the SP repeatedly in each) - that is perfectly possible; just use `EXEC` etc (still using parameterization).

You could look at how you are getting the data from ADO.NET to the REST layer. You mention IBATIS, but have you checked whether this is fast / slow compared to, say, "dapper" ?

Finally, the SP performance itself can be investigated; indexing or just a re-structuring of the SP's SQL may help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have to return 360,000 records, you have to return 360,000 records. But do you really need to return 360,000 records? Start there and work your way down.

Comment: yes. it needs to be returned..this is the max load that the system should cater. and i am not calling the rest service 300 times its one sp that im calling 300 times

Comment: Yes caching is currently in place.

Comment: So you don't actually cal the stored procedure 300 times.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much of the details, the architecture appears flawed. On one hand its considered unreasonable to lock the tables for the 6 seconds it takes to retrieve the 360,000 records using a single S.P. execution, but it fine to return a possibly inconsistent set of 360,000 records that are retrieved via multiple S.P. executions. It makes me wonder what exactly are you trying to implement and if there is a better way to design the integration between the client and the server.

For instance, if the client is retrieving a set of records that have been created since the last request, then [maybe a paged ATOM feed](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5005.txt) would be more appropriate.

What ever it is you are doing, 360,000 records is a lot of data to move between the server and the client and we should be looking at the architecture and purpose of that data transfer to make sure the current approach is appropriate.